# CSS column linked images inside a flexbox image/background aligned to bottom

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to CSS something like this, where `#box` and `#rectangle` are both linked images (buttons?) that are overlaid on a background image `#phone` aligned/attached to the bottom of the page:

[image]

```
<body>

<div id="phone" class="flexbox">
<a id="box" class="btn" href=""><img src="https://picsum.photos/135/135" /></a> 
<a id="rectangle" class="btn" href=""><img src="https://picsum.photos/135/50" /></a> 
</div>

</body>
```

```
body { 
        margin: 0; padding: 0;  
        background-position: center center; 
        background-repeat: no-repeat;  background-attachment: fixed;  background-size: cover;width:100%;
     }
.phone{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:flex-end; 
  height:100vh;
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/750x1500");
 background-size:80%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;  
        width:100%;
}
.btn{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center; 
  flex-flow: column;
   height:100vh;
}
```

[Here is my attempt so far](https://jsfiddle.net/yosun/j8furbqx/17/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**USE FLEX DIRECTION**

You can achieve this using flex-direction. Flex-direction defines the direction of items on the flex container. Since your need is to place the items(links) column wise. You can create a flex-box that lays out its items column wise.

Try pasting this on your fiddle.

HTML:

```
<body>
   <div class="entire-background">
     <div class="phone">
        <div class="links">
          <a class="btn" href=""><img src="https://picsum.photos/135/135" /></a> 
          <a class="btn" href=""><img src="https://picsum.photos/135/50" /></a>  
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
 body {
   background: #333;    // if you want some color :)
 }
 .entire-background {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
 }
.phone{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: red;
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/750x1500");
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: center;       // this centers the links. Remove this to place it on top. and add padding if you need space from the top.
  display: flex;
}
.links {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;      // this makes the items to form a column
}
```

Comment: How do you center the vertical links?

Comment: also #phone needs to be responsive

Comment: align-items: center;       // this centers the links.

Does this not center the vertical links?

Comment: For responsiveness: You can replace the height to be 100vh. If you are referring to the width, the smallest device would be galaxy fold with the width of 280px. If your requirement would not exceed 280px, you can make the width to be 280px or else use bootstrap for easy responsiveness management. But that would be out of the scope of this question.

Comment: The width of phone should be a percentage instead of absolute?

Comment: Is there a way to have the entire `  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/750x1500");` show responsibly in the phone?

Comment: Yes definitely!.

Use this in .phone class {background-position: center center; 
                background-repeat: no-repeat; 
                background-attachment: fixed;
                background-size: cover;
                width:100%;}

Comment: Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/subodhkalika/7uafqmp5/7/

Comment: but the phone needs to be responsive and fit in a percentage - looking "small" like in the image above?

Comment: You can play around with the background-position to settle the image for mobile. 

However, the image size 750 * 1500 seems absurd for the desktop website as it can distort the image. You might want to consider different images or atleast image sizes for mobile and the desktop view to make it look proper.

To show different images according to the screen size, media query can come handy.

Comment: @ina I am not able to understand your question. Please ask another question with the explanation or update the above with new queries.

Comment: I think what you are asking for this in .phone: 

{width:40%;
                height: 80vh;}

Comment: how do you get 40% and 80vh? so the idea is that the #phone div with its background image aligns to the bottom and is responsive

Comment: checking back. lmk!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
body { // you do not need the background properties here
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
     
.phone{
  position: fixed;  // this and the next 3 rules make sure the phone container is fixed to the bottom middle of the screen
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  padding: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; // makes sure your links are aligned vertically
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/750x1500");
  background-size: cover; // fills the whole container with the background image
  background-repeat: no-repeat;  
}

.btn{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: needs to be percentage